# get value from next index of object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm looping through an object. The loop is working perfectly fine, but  after the number of `value` comes to `zero` it's jumping to the next `key`.

I want after iterating from the each `key` it should go to next one.

```js
let trackOfReaction = {
  heart: 5,
  fire: 4,
  clap: 0,
  wow: 2,
  like: 1,
}

setInterval(() => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(trackOfReaction)) {
        if (value !== 0) {
        trackOfReaction[key] = value - 1
          const userReaction = {
            reaction: key,
            storedReaction: true,
          };
          console.log(userReaction)
          break;
        }
      }
    }, 2000);
```

Below is expected output

**Expected output**

```
{
  reaction: "heart",
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "fire",
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "wow",
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "like",
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "heart", // here after completing of the first set heart should print again
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "fire",
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "wow",
  storedReaction: true
},
{
  reaction: "heart",  // like became 0 so it not print, loop goes again back to heart
  storedReaction: true
},...so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

Note the splice so timeout will no longer take longer as the values turn 0

```js
const trackOfReaction = {   heart: 5,   fire: 4,   clap: 0,   wow: 2,   like: 1, };
// filter the items so we do not even process "clap"
const arr = Object.entries(trackOfReaction).filter(([key, value]) => value > 0);

let cnt = 0;
let tId = setInterval(() => {
  if (cnt >= arr.length) cnt = 0;
  const [key, value] = arr[cnt];
  if (value === 0) {
    // no need to subtract
    cnt++
    return;
  }
  const userReaction = { reaction: key, storedReaction: true, value: value };
  console.log(userReaction);

  arr[cnt][1]--; // count down the entry
  if (arr[cnt][1] === 0) arr.splice(cnt,1); // shorten the array

  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
  const cont = arr.reduce((acc, [key, value], i) => { acc += value; return acc; }, 0);
  if (cont === 0) { // stop when the array is empty or all values are 0
    clearInterval(tId);
    console.log("stopped");
    return; // stop
  }
  cnt++; // add one
}, 1000);
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, yes exactly this is how I wanted, but there is a small change here, you can see the `clap` is `0` but still it's printing in the console, what I'm trying to do is, if any of the `value` will become zero I need to skip that and move to the next one

Comment: @CodeBug I have fixed the interval now. Each time around takes the same time as the values turn 0

Comment: hi, thank you very much, this is something I'm looking for, this is so helpful